# remove the a href links border in css

Tags: html, css

```
<a href='...'><input type='button'></a>
```

I have `<a>` links when i click, it appear border. How to remove the border around

I have try  `style='border: none;'` but it is not working

Comment: You HTML is invalid. You **cannot** have an input inside an anchor.

Comment: What effect are you after?  If you want to navigate the user when a button is clicked you could do window.open or change the window location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `outline:none;`

**For Instance,**

```
a:focus{outline:none;}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the element's [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) from `:focus`:

```css
a:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

For accessibility reasons, however, you'll want to add in something which clearly shows when this link has been focussed. Otherwise some users will struggle to navigate their way around your site.